# how to return uint256 from solidity to javascript?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

I have a function in Solidity:

```
address[] contracts;

function getContractsCount() constant returns (uint256) {
      return contracts.length;
}
```

in Remix it's work perfect. I get 1, it's right, but when I call the function from javascript:

```
import FactoryContract from '../build/contracts/Factory.json';

const selectContractInstance = (contractBuild) => {
  return new Promise(res => {
    const myContract = contract(contractBuild);
    myContract.setProvider(provider);
    myContract
      .deployed()
      .then(instance => res(instance));
  })
}

var factoryContract = await selectContractInstance(FactoryContract);    

var contractCount = await factoryContract.getContractsCount.call().toNumber();
```

I get wrong number - 0.

How to return uint from Solidity to JavaScript from contract function

**[UPDATE]**
**---------**

**Solidity Code**

```
address[] public contracts;
 TokenFactory public newContract;

function createContract(uint _totalSupply, string _name, string _symbol, uint _decimal) payable returns(uint256 t) {
  newContract = new TokenFactory(_totalSupply, _name, _symbol, _decimal);
  contracts.push(newContract);
  return (contracts.length);
} //return 1, it's right

function getContractsCount() constant returns (uint256 length) {
  return (contracts.length);
} // after that the function return 0, it's wrong!
```

**JavaScript Code not change**

Comment: I add gas limit for function in JavaScript and it resolve problem. Anyway thanks for answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the contract address or ABI is not correctly set in your case because I tested and it works perfectly.

Please check if correct contract address and ABI is updated in your javascript file.

***[Update]***

***-----------------------***

As you asked, I am attaching my code:

***Solidity Code:***

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract testContract {
    uint256 num1;

    address[] contracts = [0x36eaf79c12e96a3dc6f53426c, 0xf235aa56dd96bda02acfb361e];

    function getContractsCount() constant returns (uint256) {
          return contracts.length;
    }

}
```

***jQuery code:***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function contractInvocation() {
        var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        var abi = <ABI>;
        var testContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
        var contractInstance = testContract.at('<Contract Address>');
        var y = contractInstance.getContractsCount.call({from:web3.eth.accounts[0]}).c[0];
        console.log(y);
});
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, now it look like:

`address[] contracts;`

`function getContractsCountOne() constant returns (uint256) {
      contracts.push(newAddress);
      return contracts.length;
}`

`function getContractsCountTwo() constant returns (uint256) {
      return contracts.length;
}`

From JavaScript, I call  `getContractsCountOne()` and get 1, then i just call `getContractsCountTwo()` and I get 0, but why? 

contract address and ABI set correct.

Comment: Can i see your code, please?

Comment: I sae your code in comment, that doesn't seems to be correct. If your function is constant `function getContractsCountOne() constant returns (uint256) {`, it won't be able to do any write operations which you are doing (Pushing and element to array).

Comment: Yes your right. But sorry, it copy-paste, in original code `constant` does not exist. The function set like payable.

Comment: Can you share your exact complete code in the question?

Comment: I update solidity code. JavaScript code not be change.

Comment: createContract() return length as 1, but getContractsCount() return as 0